# Replacement steps in operation BlockDeclarationInstantiation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next

Recently, I've noticed that operation [BlockDeclarationInstantiation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-blockdeclarationinstantiation) has some changes. Take a look at these points:

> Perform ! env.CreateMutableBinding(dn, false). NOTE: This step is
> replaced in section B.3.2.6.

and

> Perform env.InitializeBinding(fn, fo). NOTE: This step is replaced in
> section B.3.2.6.

Earlier I've not seen them.
In draft specification we have for BlockDeclarationInstantiation [this](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-web-compat-blockdeclarationinstantiation).
In comparison with [ECMAScript 7](https://262.ecma-international.org/7.0/#sec-additional-ecmascript-features-for-web-browsers) we have not this point, but in [ECMAScript 8](https://262.ecma-international.org/8.0/#sec-web-compat-blockdeclarationinstantiation) we have part of that what we have in the draft version.

1. Why do we have so differences for BlockDeclarationInstantiation compability among versions? Shouldn't compatibility be the same?
2. Why has not it done simple by inserting new points in current algorithm of BlockDeclarationInstantiation?
3. What do replacements actual do especial that they didn't before?

Comment: Annex B has always been specified, just not referenced from the main algorithms

Comment: "*Recently … has some changes*" - can you clarify what versions you are comparing and what exactly has changed?

Comment: @Bergi I've done, take a look please.

Answer (score 0):

These "replacements" are not due to differences in version.

If you look at it, they are specified in [Annex B](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-additional-ecmascript-features-for-web-browsers), "Additional ECMAScript Features for Web Browsers".

This annex contains alternative rules specifically for web browsers. As the header says, rules defined there are required only if the host is a browser, optional otherwise.

Annex B is mostly for specifying legacy language features that weren't specified but were implemented in browsers. These two are for `FunctionDeclaration`s inside `BlockStatement`s, a legacy feature first specified in ES6.

The [ES6 spec](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-block-level-function-declarations-web-legacy-compatibility-semantics) gives a detailed description of this feature, with a different set of rather-complex modifications.

Comment: That about you're talking about I know. Take a look, there was no annex for BlockDeclarationInstantiation in ECMAScript7. But there is annex in ECMAScript8 for Block, but incomplete in comparison vs current ECMAScript. As you can see were differences, so my question is still exist.

Comment: Can you edit your answer in conformity of my questions?